# Error: File "sn-jnl.cls" not found

Tags: texstudio, overleaf

[image][image]

So, the thing is i was using this code on overleaf (it worked fine there) and i wanted to switch to texstudio because of the compiling limits on overleaf. So i copied the whole command from overleaf tex file and pasted in the texstudio. But it says "Error: File 'sn-jnl.cls' not found." when i run it. how do i fix it?

Comment: That is a Springer Journal class not in texlive/miktex, you could get a copy from the publisher or you presumably have a copy in your overleaf project so you could copy it from there

Comment: Incidentally, TeXstudio is just a front end to a TeX distribution. Which TeX distribution is installed on your system, and when was it last updated?

Comment: yes, i do have this file in overleaf. but where do i copy it.

Comment: I have miktex and i installed it today.

Comment: just place it in the same folder as your document will work

Comment: rather than copy individual files you could have downloaded the whole project as a zip file from overleaf